# MySQL 5.7 32-bit table is full on unix

Tags: mysql, innodb

As per the subject, I'm receiving an error on an InnoDB table: "table is full" when it reached 4GB the filesystem is far from being full so the only thing that I'm thinking right now is that the issue is with the fact that the MySQL installation is a 32-bit.

Can this be the case even if we are in a linux environment?

Comment: See [1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730579/205233)

Comment: If data amount is far from file size then execute OPTIMIZE TABLE and compact it.

Comment: 32 bits are still 32 bits, whether on Windows, on Linux, or on Mars.

Comment: Please run `SELECT @@global.innodb_file_per_table;` and tell us if this is 0 or 1.

Comment: 4GB is the largest file size addressable by a 32-bit file pointer. I recommend that you upgrade your software to the 64-bit version if you need larger files.

Comment: Please be more specific about the OS, filesystem type, etc.  FAT32 limits a file to 4GB.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291683/mysql-innodb-the-table-is-full-error and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits